# how to attach point of plot in for loop without using linspace?

Tags: python

I needed to see the image of a sequence, that's why I chose Python, I got in trouble along the way, that I do not use `np.linspace` , so the points in the loop are not connected, but I needed to points get connected like they do in `np.linspace` like they are in a line, but I have no idea how to implement this particular sequence.

the sequence :

$${a_n} = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}$$
= 2 + 1/2! + 1/3! +...+1/n!

```
y = 1
fac = 1
for n in range(80) :
    fac = fac * (n+1)
    y = y +  1 / fac
    plt.plot(n , y , alpha = 0.5 , color = 'red' , linestyle = 'solid' , 
                linewidth = 2 , marker = '.' , markersize = 2 ,
                markerfacecolor = 'blue' , markeredgecolor = 'blue' )

plt.ylim([-1,4])
plt.savefig('Ascending Highly bounded sequence convergence.png')

plt.clf() #clear figure
```

the result :
[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That image is not the result of the code?

Comment: @karina no. It is result of code and it works fine.

Comment: You clearly wrote plt.plot and color red, linestyle solid, linewidth 2, how am I only seeing plt.scatter here?

Comment: @karina sorry I don't understand what you mean. :')

Comment: My fault. I missed the fact that your plt.plot is **in** the for-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you don't see a line connecting the points is that you call the `plot` function for every point. Because of this, matplotlib plots lots of single points with no connections in between.

To get a line between the points you have to call the `plot` function with a collection of data points.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

X = range(80)
Y = []

y = 1
fac = 1
for n in X:
    fac = fac * (n+1)
    y = y +  1 / fac
    Y.append(y)
    
plt.plot(X, Y, alpha = 0.5 , color = 'red' , linestyle = 'solid' , 
            linewidth = 2 , marker = '.' , markersize = 2 ,
            markerfacecolor = 'blue' , markeredgecolor = 'blue' )

plt.ylim([-1,4])
plt.savefig('Ascending Highly bounded sequence convergence.png')

plt.clf() #clear figure
```

Comment: _The reason why you don't see a line connecting the points is that you call the plot function for every point_ good observation! I totally missed that